# How were walkways found and added to Google Maps or OSM?

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, machine-learning, deep-learning

Does Google Maps or OSM use any deep learning or machine learning model to extract walkways from satellite images? Examples of walkways are the green lines in the picture here. I wonder how they were added to the map in scale?

Most papers about pedestrian network extraction I found online are at least 7 years old. I wonder if there are any more recent work in walkway extraction?

[image: UW campus showing walkways in green]

Comment: Maybe in some cities, would be my guess. I know they use contractors to digitize & correct roads and pathways. I think some of the data comes from authoritative sources while some data is generated using data from street view cars and google maps users.

Answer (score 3):

In this case the source is Open Street Map - you can get the history for the paths (walk ways).

Example:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/4708373/history

> you can find out that it was created 13 years ago and the 'Potlatch
> alpha' was the original source of editing.

Potlatch was a flash based editor for OpenStreetMap this has been superseded by
Potlatch 2 architecture (Javascript)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potlatch_(software)

update the iD editor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID_(software) is the current software for editing in the browser

Answer (score 1):

I would say most, if not all, of openstreetmap walkways are manually added from tracing satellite imagery or GPS traces. Iv'e never heard of anything automated regarding walkways in openstreetmap. Coastlines and landcover has seen extensive use of automation in some form, but that was mostly early in the project. Adding massive amounts of data today is a bit harder, since you need to not destroy anything.